# ./jdk-6u34-linux-i586.bin: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, java

I am trying to install jdk for 32-bit OS. Followed the below steps,

1. `wget http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/6u34-b04/jdk-6u34-linux-i586.bin`
2. `chmod u+x jdk-6u34-linux-i586.bin`
3. `./jdk-6u34-linux-i586.bin`

But while trying to do step4 the below error happens,

```
./jdk-6u34-linux-i586.bin
./jdk-6u34-linux-i586.bin: No such file or directory
```

What may be the pblm.

Comment: @Kateyou shouldn't run the jdk.bin file, if you want to install jdk only download jdk folder and set your JAVA_HOME variable.

Comment: What is the size of your downloaded file?

Comment: `. jdk-6u34-linux-i586.bin` with a space after the dot.

Comment: Are you sure that you actually downloaded the `.bin` file? Downloading from `download.oracle.com` usually requires to agree to the licensing terms, which is not done when using plain `wget`

Comment: yeah, tats right, the bin file was not actually downloaded.. Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to download that file, you must have accepted the license in the previous page. So the wget command that you tried would only have downloaded the HTML page saying that complains that you have not accepted the license.

You can bypass this by adding adding the cookie to wget command that is used in that site.

Try the following wget command to download the file.

```
wget --header "Cookie: gpw_e24=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com" \
 -O jdk-6u34-linux-i586.bin \
 http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/6u34-b04/jdk-6u34-linux-i586.bin
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to look at the size of the file you've downloaded and then the contents. Good money is that you've got an HTML page asking you to accept the OTN license terms...

Anyways, installing JDK on a linux system is easily done with package managers such as Aptitude (Debian) or Yum (RPM based system).

Cheers,

Comment: +1 for the license terms, but one thing where I personally do not rely on the package managers is when I want to install a vanilla JDK/JRE package - I had too much trouble in the past with the `alternative` systems and/or some arbitrary version of OpenJDK being pulled in instead of the plain JDK/JRE ...

Comment: I agree, but for starters it's a good route to get *some* form of JDK on the system...